# Make ul the same height as it's li's

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

How can I make it so that the ul is the height of the li it contains.

```
<div class="row">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="small-4 columns">L1</li>
            <li class="small-4 columns">L2</li>
            <li class="small-4 columns">L3</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

I have a border around the UL and it's not 'below' the LIs, it cuts through the middle of them.

Comment: Sounds like an overflow or float issue. JSfiddle please

Comment: Can you post your CSS?

Comment: overflow: hidden; on the UL should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @ Michael this worked, why is this?

Comment: You know I have never really known an exact answer as to why it operates this way.  What I do know is that when you float an element, other elements near it don't respect it's height.  Consequently if the height of the parent element is set to auto (default) - it's height will be 0px unless you put something else in that container (add a <p> tag with text inside your UL without the overflow code and you'll see the UL will have some height)  Overflow:hidden; prevents this 0 height issue from happening.

Comment: This site explains floated elements the best: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/float/

Halfway down the page you'll see details on collapsed parent elements.